# Centering a <div> with a width of 100%?

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

So I can successfully center a div using the following CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1024px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

I then have the container inside the body tags, covering all the displayed page content. This works just fine.

The issue is that when I do the same thing but set the width to 100%, the page is no longer centered. This restricts how dynamic I can make my page, as I have to then create a container for each screen width (in px).

How can I create a container that will center my page with a width of 100%?

Many thanks.

Comment: are you talking about centering the content? because otherwise, if the width is 100% - there's no meaning to "centering" the parent.

Could you show an example of the desired outcome?

Comment: I read the question multiple times but still didn't have a clue about "centering a 100% width element" thing. Something's wrong about either my perception or the question.

Comment: answer is, **you can not**. setting width to 100% of parent or viewport will stretch the element to the edges of parent or viewport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to just center a div within a container.Then you have style div within container as margin:0 auto; . Below is simple demonstration:

```css
.container_
{
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
  background:green;
}

.centreBox
{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_">
  <div class="centreBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want div to place it horizontally as well as vertically in center

```css
.container_
{
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
  position:relative;
  background:green;
}

.centreBox
{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_">
  <div class="centreBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

And you want to place div with width 100% ,then it will occupy whole horizontal space available.There you can only apply vertical centering:

```css
.container_
{
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
  position:relative;
  background:green;
}

.centreBox
{
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_">
  <div class="centreBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have text inside that container which you want to center, add `text-align: center;` to the CSS rule you posted.

If you have other elements inside the container which you want to center, apply `margin: 0 auto` to them, as you did to the container itself (they need a width less than 100% for that to have any effect...)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a minimal working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS center</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .content {
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 100px;
            width: 80%;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The blue content is 80% of the red container width and is centered in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center content you should add margin: 0 auto; to content.Not to container.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: And make sure you set a bigger width for the content on mobile !